# All dates returned even other column data is absent

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the script and data

```
CREATE TABLE TB_TEST (
    ManDate date,
    Amount float
)    

INSERT INTO TB_Test Values ('2023-Mar-14', 13.0)
INSERT INTO TB_Test Values ('2023-Mar-13', 13.5)
INSERT INTO TB_Test Values ('2023-Mar-10', 12.8)
INSERT INTO TB_Test Values ('2023-Mar-8', 14.6)
```

And the query returns data

```
SELECT Mandate, Amount 
FROM TB_TEST
```

[image]

However, if my client does not make any products on some dates, they want to show the no production dates with Amount = 0 like rows in yellow as below:

[image]

This means that the Mandate column shows everyday until the current date.

Thank you in advance

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: This is a very common problem , for which you can find many examples out there. The key is you need a calendar table of some form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a date range for the query, then you could use a CTE to generate the dates that will have no products. If I modify an example I've found here - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/ - the solution would look like this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate  date = '20230101';

DECLARE @CutoffDate date = '20230315';

;WITH seq(n) AS 
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM seq
  WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)
),
d(d) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, @StartDate) FROM seq
)
SELECT d as Mandate, (case when tb.Amount is not null then tb.Amount else 0) as Amount FROM d
LEFT OUTER JOIN TB_TEST tb on d.Mandate = t.d
ORDER BY d desc
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

This query would select all the dates based on the range you provided, and then join them to your table that has your actual dates/amounts in it. For any row that has an amount, it takes the amount from your table - for any other row it sets the Amount to be 0 (see the case statement).